# Rename files to unique names and move them into a single destination directory

Tags: bash

i have 100s of directories with same filename of `content.html` along with other files.

I am trying to copy all these `content.html` files under 1 directory, but since they have same name, it overwrites each other

**so how can i rename and move all these under 1 directory**

Eg:

> ```
> ./0BD3D9D2-F8B1-4472-95C2-13319650A45C:
> card.png  content.html    note.xhtml  quickLook.png   snippet.txt
>
> ./0EA34DB4-CD56-42BE-91DA-F631E44FB6E0:
> card.png  content.html    note.xhtml  quickLook.png   related     snippet.txt
>
> ./1A33F29E-3938-4C2F-BA99-6B98FD045742:
> card.png  content.html    note.xhtml  quickLook.png   snippet.txt
> ```

command i tried:

1. rename content.html to content

   find . -type f | grep content.html | while read f; do mv $f ${f/.html/}; done
2. append number to filename "content" to make it unique

   find . -type f | grep content | while read f; do i=1; echo mv $f $f$i.html; i=i+1; done

MacBook-Pro$ find . -type f | grep content | while read f; do i=1; echo mv $f $f$i.html; i=i+1; done

```
mv ./0BD3D9D2-F8B1-4472-95C2-13319650A45C/content ./0BD3D9D2-F8B1-4472-95C2-13319650A45C/content1.html

mv ./0EA34DB4-CD56-42BE-91DA-F631E44FB6E0/content ./0EA34DB4-CD56-42BE-91DA-F631E44FB6E0/content1.html
mv ./1A33F29E-3938-4C2F-BA99-6B98FD045742/content ./1A33F29E-3938-4C2F-BA99-6B98FD045742/content1.html
```

3. once above step is successful, i should be able do this to achieve my desired output:

   find . -type f | grep content | while read f; do mv $f ../; done

however, i am sure i can do this in 1 step command and also my step 2 is not working (incrementing i)

**any idea why step2 is not working??**

Answer (score 2):

***bash*** script:

```
#!/bin/bash    
find . -type f -name content.html | while IFS= read -r f; do
    name=$(basename $f)
    ((++i))
    mv "$f" "for_content/${name%.*}$i.html"
done
```

---

replace `for_content` with your *destination* folder name

Comment: thanks this worked!
just need find . -type (.) is missing

Answer (score 0):

Suppose in your base directory, you create a folder named `final` for storing
`content.html` files, then do something like below

```
find . -path ./final -prune -o -name "content.html" -print0 |
while read -r -d '' name
do 
mv "$name" "./final/content$(mktemp -u XXXX).html"
# mktemp with -u option just creates random characters, or it is just a dry run
done
```

At the end you'll get all the content.html files under `./final` folder in the format `contentXXXX.html` where `XXXX` are random characters.

---

<sup>**Note:**`-path ./final -prune -o` in `find` prevents it from descending to our results folder.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The inode of the of the files should be unique and so you could use the following:

```
find $(pwd) -name "content.html" -printf %f" "%i" "%p"\n" | awk '{ system("mv "$3" <directorytomoveto>"$2$1) }'
```

Comment: find: -printf: unknown primary or operator

Comment: I've changed to search for content.html

Comment: i was not using .py even earlier, so the error is still the same, may be because this is not linux - this is mac (Darwin Kernel Version 16.1.0) ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use something like this:

```
find . -type f -name 'test' | awk 'BEGIN{ cnt=0 }{ printf "mv %s ./output-dir/content_%03d.txt\n", $0, cnt++ }' | bash;
```

You can replace ./output-dir/ with your destination directory

Example:

```
[root@sl7-o2 test]# ls -R
.:
1  2  3  output-dir

./1:
test

./2:
test

./3:
test

./output-dir:

[root@sl7-o2 test]# find . -type f -name 'test' | awk 'BEGIN{ cnt=0 }{ printf "mv %s ./output-dir/content_%03d.txt\n", $0, cnt++ }' | bash;

[root@sl7-o2 test]# ls ./output-dir/
content_000.txt  content_001.txt  content_002.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `shopt -s globstar` to grab all `content.html` files recursively and then use a loop to rename them:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -o globstar
counter=0
dest_dir=/path/to/destination
for f in **/content.html; do  # pick up all content.html files
  [[ -f "$f" ]] || continue   # skip if not a regular file
  mv "$f" "$dest_dir/content_$((++counter).html"
done
```